# ValueError: should I reshape the input layer

Tags: python, model, mlp

This is the error I've got today which is,

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3072 but received input with shape [None, 32, 32, 3]

Here below is my code.

*What is the best way to solve it? changing the last two liines or reshape im?*

Thanks in advance.

````
import keras
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout
from keras.models import model_from_json
import os

num_classes = 10
im_rows = 32
im_cols = 32
im_size = im_rows *im_cols *3

(X_train, y_train),(X_test, y_test) = cifar10.load_data()
X_train = X_train.reshape(-1, im_size).astype('float32')/255
X_test = X_test.reshape(-1, im_size).astype('float32')/255

y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, activation ='relu', input_shape=(im_size,)))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
    loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                 batch_size=32, epochs=30,
                 verbose=1,
                 validation_data = (X_test, y_test))
model.summary()

score = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test, verbose =1)
print('accuracy=', score[1], 'loss=', score[0])

# serialize model to JSON
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
# serialize weights to HDF5
model.save_weights("cifar10_mlp_weight.h5")
print("Saved model to disk")

json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("cifar10_mlp_weight.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")

im = cv2.imread('/Users/benno/Documents/Python/data/images/car.jpg')
im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im = cv2.resize(im, (32, 32))
plt.imshow(im) 
plt.show()

#This line shows error#
r = model.predict(np.array([im]), batch_size=32, verbose =1)
res = r[0]```
````

Comment: a simple flatten layer in the first position of the network can be enough

Comment: @Marco Cerliani Solved it! Cheers mate